# Which SQL Server version to install on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a test server running Windows Server 2008 R2 that I want to put SQL Server 2008 onto. I have an MSDN subscription and thought I could install (x64 version) SQL2008 but the installation warned me this wasn't compatible with this version of windows (reporting that I am running Windows 7).

When I log onto my MSDN to download an update the only SQL Server R2 options I have are for Express edition or Enterprise evaluation (I am logged in to subscriber downloads). Is there no standard R2 edition or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2008 install warns you that there are known compatibility issues. This is correct.

Ignore the warning (i.e. run the install), then install the latest service pack for SQL Server 2008 (and the latest cumulative update) and you are ok.

The warning is explicitly for the non-sp1 version of SQL Server 2008. There are known issues. They got fixed in a service pack.

Comment: +1 for information, but -1 for spelling? 
(Sorry if English is not your native language though)

Comment: +1, and spelling fixed! ;)

Comment: Thanks - I've installed SQL fine, just downloading SP1 for x64 now.

Comment: Non-native engllish speaker, Guy ;) Apology accepted.

Answer (score 3):

SQL 2008 is the latest released version of MS SQL server, I would suggest this is the correct version. The reason it is failing is likely:

The .NET 3.5 framework is not enabled on Windows 2008 R2 by default - see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955725) KB article

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the requirements for installing SQL Server 2008 [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx). As per the link, you cannot install Enterprise edition on Win7. You can try Express or Standard edition.

Comment: Dan has Windows Server 2008 not Windows 7

Comment: my bad, miss read the question.

Answer (score 0):

To run SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2, you need to install SQL Server 2008 **SP1**.  You can either install this after the fact, or create a slipstreamed installation point.

See [Microsoft Support: How to update or slipstream an installation of SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955392)

I use a slipstreamed installation point and run setup.exe from the command line - this is much faster, since you don't have to click through the setup wizard or wait for the 'Setup Support files' to install.

Just open an elevated command prompt and run this command to install SQL, Analysis Services, Reporting Services, SQL Management Studio and BIDS in about 15 minutes:

> C:\SQL2008SP1Slipstreamed\Setup.exe /q
>   /ACTION=Install
>   /FEATURES=SQL,FullText,AS,RS,Tools
>   /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
>   /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Authority\Network
>   Service" /RSSVCACCOUNT="NT
>   Authority\Network Service"
>   /ASSVCACCOUNT="NT Authority\Network
>   Service" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT
>   Authority\Network Service"
>   /SQLSVCStartuptype=2
>   /RSSVCStartupType=2
>   /ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE=2
>   /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=2
>   /BROWSERSVCStartupType=2
>   /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators"
>   /ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators"
>   /SQMREPORTING=1 /ERRORREPORTING=1
>   /INDICATEPROGRESS